# Issues with virtualenv mod_wsgi, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Tags: python, mod-wsgi

I am trying for the first time in my life to deploy a django project on windows 10. I have followed the steps here: https://www.codementor.io/@aswinmurugesh/deploying-a-django-application-in-windows-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-uhl2xq09e

Anyway, everytime I try to run httpd.exe in Apache, I would get the following error

```
[Tue Jul 07 01:13:02.404342 2020] [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 9256:tid 784] AH00419: master_main: create child process failed. Exiting.
[Tue Jul 07 01:14:20.666201 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 13936:tid 788] AH00455: Apache/2.4.41 (Win32) PHP/7.3.12 mod_wsgi/4.7.1 Python/3.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jul 07 01:14:20.666201 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 13936:tid 788] AH00456: Apache Lounge VS16 Server built: Aug  9 2019 16:32:28
[Tue Jul 07 01:14:20.666201 2020] [core:notice] [pid 13936:tid 788] AH00094: Command line: 'httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.41'
[Tue Jul 07 01:14:20.672180 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 13936:tid 788] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 16108
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = 'c:\pythonvenv\djangoproj'
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.41\\bin\\httpd.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = 'c:\\pythonvenv\\djangoproj'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'c:\\pythonvenv\\djangoproj'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.41\\bin\\httpd.exe'
  sys.prefix = 'c:\\pythonvenv\\djangoproj'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'c:\\pythonvenv\\djangoproj'
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\pythonvenv\\djangoproj\\Scripts\\python38.zip',
    'c:\\pythonvenv\\djangoproj\\DLLs',
    'c:\\pythonvenv\\djangoproj\\lib',
    'C:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.41\\bin',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00002708 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
[Tue Jul 07 01:14:22.542101 2020] [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 13936:tid 788] AH00419: master_main: create child process failed. Exiting.
```

I have added this below to my httpd.conf in apache.

```
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/pythonvenv/djangoproj/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp38-win32.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/pythonvenv/djangoproj"
```

The main issue here is this: If I change the **WSGIPythonHome** to my actual python installation path: `C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\`

The apache webserver is able to run.

However if pythonhome is the dir of my virtualenv as mentioned above, it won't work and give the error on top.

Why is this and how can I fix it?